# Python Centralized Dictionary Access

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wish to create a file to contain list of static lookup dictionaries. This file would be accessed by all the other files in the project so essentially I am trying to avoid data redundancy and putting in a centralized control.

To get it done, I created a class, created lookup dictionaries and added getter methods to access. But when I try to use the dict, my get methods can't seem to have vsibility into the globally declared dicts.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
class global_lookup: 

    PROVINCE_DICT = {
        "AB" : "Alberta",
        "BC" : "British Columbia",
        "MB" : "Manitoba",
        "NB" : "New Brunswick",
        "NL" : "Newfoundland and Labrador",
        "NT" : "Northwest Territories",
        "NS" : "Nova Scotia",
        "NU" : "Nunavut",
        "ON" : "Ontario",
        "PE" : "Prince Edward Island",
        "QC" : "Quebec",
        "SK" : "Saskatchewan",
        "YT" : "Yukon"
    }

    def get_province_short(province_long):
        for prov_shrt, prov_long in PROVINCE_DICT.items():
            if province_long == prov_long:
                return prov_shrt
            else:
                raise DatahubError(F"get_province_short - Province data for {province_long} could not be located")    

    def get_province_long(province_short): 
        if province_short in PROVINCE_DICT.keys():
            return PROVINCE_DICT[province_short]
        else:
            raise DatahubError(F"get_province_long - Province data for {province_short} could not be located")
```

Since this is going to be a static dict, I intend to include this class and call the methods to access the long and short province names.

For instance, I am calling this from another class using:

`global_lookup.get_province_long('ON')`

And the error that I get is:

`` `name 'PROVINCE_DICT' is not defined ``

I expect `'Ontario'` to be returned.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation?

Comment: Please ensure your indentation is correct; currently it's impossible to understand what is going on here. You have a class, but what is inside it? Are all those functions actually methods? If so why don't they take `self`? But if the whole thing is a class, why do you say the dict is global? It's not, it's inside the class.

Comment: My apologies. I tried to correct the indentation. Let me know if it looks understandeable. I've just included the class where I am thinking the problem is.

Comment: `PROVINCE_DICT` is gone now, though. Is it also inside the class?

Comment: @Ry I added it back. Basically the POVINCE_DICT isn't accessible to those two get functions. I come form Java background and have very limited understanding of python.

Comment: @glibdud I intended to run them from the class.

Comment: Python is not Java. You don't need a class here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dictionary will be an attribute of every instance of the class. By convention, the instance is called `self` inside a method. It gets passed to every method automatically, as the first argument. That gives you a way to refer to the instance: it's called `self`. Then you can get at the things it owns.

Try this:

```
class GlobalLookup:  # More conventional class name in Python

    PROVINCE_DICT = {
        "AB" : "Alberta",
        "BC" : "British Columbia",
        "MB" : "Manitoba",
        "NB" : "New Brunswick",
        "NL" : "Newfoundland and Labrador",
        "NT" : "Northwest Territories",
        "NS" : "Nova Scotia",
        "NU" : "Nunavut",
        "ON" : "Ontario",
        "PE" : "Prince Edward Island",
        "QC" : "Quebec",
        "SK" : "Saskatchewan",
        "YT" : "Yukon"
    }

    def get_province_short(self, province_long):
        for prov_shrt, prov_long in self.PROVINCE_DICT.items():
            if province_long == prov_long:
                return prov_shrt
        else:
            raise DatahubError(f"get_province_short - Province data for {province_long} could not be located")    

    def get_province_long(self, province_short): 
        prov_long = self.PROVINCE_DICT.get(province_short)
        if prov_long is None:
            raise DatahubError(f"get_province_long - Province data for {province_short} could not be located")
        return prov_long
```

I also used the `get` method on the dictionary, because it's there.

Note that the `else` in `get_province_short()` should be on the `for`, because you only want to raise an error if the `for` loop finished normally.

Comment: the points you made are super helpful - Class name, usage of Get instead of [], else for the for loop. Appreciate the time you took out to explain.

However, it looks like when I used the code you recommended, I get the ```get_province_long() missing 1 required positional argument: 'province_short'
``` error. 

Had to add @classmethod decorator to fix it.

Comment: @SushantVasishta Did you call the method with an argument? You need to pass in `province_short`, eg `gl = GlobalLookup(); gl.get_prvince_long('YT')`.

Comment: oh yes. I just added the @classmethod to your code and it worked.

Comment: @SushantVasishta Okay, but you don't need to since you never reference the class, only the instance.

Answer (score 1):

`PROVINCE_DICT` is a class attribute of `global_lookup`. It is not automatically added to the namespace of the methods. Since you intend to call these methods directly from the class, and since you need access to the class attributes, you should declare these methods as class methods. For example:

```
@classmethod
def get_province_short(cls, province_long):
    for prov_shrt, prov_long in cls.PROVINCE_DICT.items():
        if province_long == prov_long:
            return prov_shrt
        else:
            raise DatahubError(F"get_province_short - Province data for {province_long} could not be located")
```

Note the `@classmethod` decorator which will cause a reference to the class to be added to the method signature. We use that reference (`cls`) to access `PROVINCE_DICT`.

Comment: Very helpful @glibdud. I never realized what the decorators are used for. My first use case right here. Appreciate the help.

Comment: You can access class attributes through instances of the class. This does not need to be a class method.

Comment: @kwinkunks Sure, you *can*, but the asker indicated that he planned to call the methods from the class directly without instantiating.

Comment: @glibdud Okay, I totally missed that, thanks. And also I don't understand it. Hm.

Answer (score 1):

`PROVINCE_DICT` is an instance variable, so we can directly access instance variable through class name, like `class_name.variable_name` in the method of the class.

```
class global_lookup: 

    PROVINCE_DICT = {
      "AB" : "Alberta",
      "BC" : "British Columbia",
      "MB" : "Manitoba",
      "NB" : "New Brunswick",
      "NL" : "Newfoundland and Labrador",
      "NT" : "Northwest Territories",
      "NS" : "Nova Scotia",
      "NU" : "Nunavut",
      "ON" : "Ontario",
      "PE" : "Prince Edward Island",
      "QC" : "Quebec",
      "SK" : "Saskatchewan",
      "YT" : "Yukon"
    }

    def get_province_short(province_long):
        for prov_shrt, prov_long in global_lookup.PROVINCE_DICT.items(): #updated
            if province_long == prov_long:
                return prov_shrt
            else:
                raise DatahubError(F"get_province_short - Province data for {province_long} could not be located")    

    def get_province_long(province_short): 
        if province_short in global_lookup.PROVINCE_DICT.keys(): # update
            return global_lookup.PROVINCE_DICT[province_short] #updated
        else:
            raise DatahubError(F"get_province_long - Province data for {province_short} could not be located")
```

Method call :
`print(global_lookup.get_province_long('ON'))`

Output:
[image]

Comment: using the class name along with the method name solved my issue.